# how run a flink jar in the pod

Tags: apache-flink

I ran below flink cmd within job pod :

`./opt/flink/bin/flink run ./opt/flink/examples/batch/WordCount.jar`

Then it shows me error, I have no ideas how to fix it, but same cmd is ok in local flink. dashboard

> Executing WordCount example with default input data set.
> Use --input to specify file input.
> Printing result to stdout. Use --output to specify output path.
> The program finished with the following exception:
> org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
> at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:302)
> at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:198)
> at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:149)
> at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:699)
> at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:232)
> at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:916)
> at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:992)
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:30)
> at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:992)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
> at org.apache.flink.util.ExceptionUtils.rethrow(ExceptionUtils.java:277)
> at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(ExecutionEnvironment.java:981)
> at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.executeAsync(ContextEnvironment.java:124)
> at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.execute(ContextEnvironment.java:72)
> at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.java:873)
> at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.collect(DataSet.java:413)
> at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.print(DataSet.java:1652)
> at org.apache.flink.examples.java.wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:96)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:288)
> ... 8 more
> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
> at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(ExecutionEnvironment.java:976)
> ... 19 more
> Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
> at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$submitJob$7(RestClusterClient.java:366)
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:870)
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:852)
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$8(FutureUtils.java:292)
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:561)
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:929)
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:442)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.util.RestClientException: [Not found.]
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient.parseResponse(RestClient.java:390)
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient.lambda$submitRequest$3(RestClient.java:374)
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:952)
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:926)
> ... 4 more

Comment: Those look like the errors one gets when there is no Flink cluster running.

Comment: This is not the usual way to run Flink in a pod -- have you looked at the documentation? https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/kubernetes.html and https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/native_kubernetes.html.

Comment: @DavidAnderson the error show me [Not found.], I'm not sure which one not find. I can do savepoint by cmd.